# Entity Framework : join two tables and where clause

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble working with Entity Framework and PostgreSQL, does anybody know how to join two tables and use the second table as a where clause?

The select I want to do in Entity Framework would be in SQL:

```
SELECT ai.id, ai.title, ai.description, ai.coverimageurl 
FROM app_information ai 
INNER JOIN app_languages al on al.id = ai.languageid
WHERE al.languagecode = 'es'
```

Currently I have this

```
var appInformationToReturn = context.app_information
     .Join(
          context.app_language,
          ai => ai.languageid,
          al => al.id,
          (ai, al) => new AppInformation()
          {
               id = ai.id,
               title = ai.title,
               description = ai.description,
               coverimageurl = ai.coverimageurl
          })
     .Where()
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't know how to build the `where` clause.

Comment: `.Where(x => x.languagecode="es")`. Add property `languagecode` in `AppInformation` class. you can also use as `new { x,y,z.....}` in place of `new AppInformation()`

Comment: Honestly I don't see any reason for that join, since the principal table is not used for anything in the query. Not to mention there should be a navigation property to be used when needed instead of a manual join.

Comment: This post needs more details and clarity. Would be nice to see a full db context.

Comment: Btw, LINQ is not SQL. Not only `Select` is last, but other operators does not require to be in the same order as SQL. For instance, there could be multiple `Where`, and they could be at any point of the query chain. In your case, you could simply insert `Where` inside the `Join` , e.g. `.Join(context.app_language.Where(al => al.languagecode = "es"), ...`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Like this:

```
var appInformationToReturn = context.app_information
     .Join(
          context.app_language,
          ai => ai.languageid,
          al => al.id,
          (ai, al) => new
          {
               id = ai.id,
               title = ai.title,
               description = ai.description,
               coverimageurl = ai.coverimageurl,
               lang = al.languagecode
          })
     .Where(x => x.lang == "es")
     .Select(x => new AppInformation()
     {
          id = x.id,
          title = x.title,
          description = x.description,
          coverimageurl = x.coverimageurl
     })
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Update (2023/03/26):** Lately this answer got some attention so I decided to update and combine it with the first part of the answer provided by @Serge.

```
var item = (
     from ai in context.app_information
     join al in context.app_language on ai.languageid equals al.id 
     where (al.languagecode == "es")
     select new AppInformation 
     {
          id = ai.id,
          title = ai.title,
          description = ai.description,
          coverimageurl = ai.coverimageurl
     }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```cs
var item = (
    from ai in context.app_information
    join al in context.app_language on ai.languageid equals al.id 
    where (al.languagecode == "es")
    select new AppInformation 
    {
        id = ai.id,
        title = ai.title,
        description = ai.description,
        coverimageurl = ai.coverimageurl
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

or try  shorter

```cs
var item = context.app_information
    .Where(ai => ai.app_language.languagecode == "es")
    .Select(ai => new AppInformation 
    {
        id = ai.id,
        title = ai.title,
        description = ai.description,
        coverimageurl = ai.coverimageurl
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: In the second code part. Where is the join? You assumed that there is a relation between tables. I know there should be relation but he asked with join.

Comment: Two are the same. The second just has a lambda syntax

Comment: It's not the same. Simple way of saying this is you assumed that there is app_language variable in app_information Entity class. He asked using join which mean maybe there is no such a variable for other Entity in app_information.