# Display FullName on DropdownListFor but submit Id - ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to  build a form for information about upcoming exams. My plan is to make a dropdown list which shows a List of teachers to chose from and who will be responsible for the exam.

Here's a simplified version of my Models:

```
public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Teacher
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Exam
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExamDate { get; set; }
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    }
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class ExamViewModel
    {
        public Exam Exam { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Person> People { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    }
```

And my `Create` action from `ExamController`:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var people = _context.People.ToList();
            var teachers = _context.Teachers.ToList();

            var viewModel = new ExamViewModel
            {
                People = people,
                Teachers = teachers,
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

I'd like to display `People.Firstname + " " + People.Surname` of all teachers on the dropdown mentioned above, but instead of submitting `People.Id` I'd like to submit `Teachers.Id` to `Exams.TeacherId`

I first tried to displaying a list of the all `FirstName` before trying displaying `FirstName` and `Surname` with the following razor html helper in my `Create` view but I already failed there as I was only able to access the properties from one single class (`Teachers`) to use is as `dataValueField` and `dataTextField` for `new SelectList()`:

```
<h2>Plan exam</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ExamController"))
{
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Exam.TeacherId, new SelectList(Model.Teachers, "Id", "FirstName"), "-- Please select --", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Teacher" })
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Exam.TeacherId)
    </div>
}
```

I'm quite new to programming so I'd be very very grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: Create an extra property with only a Getter that combines some other properties and returns it.

Comment: I tried adding a getter only property to my `Person` Model with the following code:
`public string FullName{ get { return FirstName + " " + Surname; }}`
... but I can't access data of the db with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

1. First I created a second ViewModel with a property `Id` for `Teacher.Id` and `FullName` for `Person.FirstName + " " + Person.Surname`:

```
public class TeacherViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get ; set; }
    }
```

2. Then I removed the unnecessary `IEnumerable<Person> People` from my ExamViewModel and added an `IEnumerable<>` for `Teachers` of Type `TeacherViewModel`:

```
public class ExamViewModel
    {
        public Exam Exam { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<TeacherViewModel> Teachers { get; set; }
    }
```

3. I created a join as mentionen at step 1, converted it to a list in the new `TeacherViewModel`:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var teachers = (from t in _context.Teachers
                           join p in _context.People
                           on t.PersonId equals p.Id
                           select new TeacherViewModel
                           {
                               Id = t.Id,
                               FullName = p.FirstName + " " + p.Surname,
                           }).ToList();

            var viewModel = new ExamViewModel
            {
                Teachers = teachers,
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

4. I added a `Save()` method to the controller:

```
public ActionResult Save(Exams exam)
        {
            _context.Exams.Add(exam);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Exams");
        }
```

5. Added the submit button to the View and changed the action name beside `Html.BeginForm(` to `Save` as it will handle saving the variables from the form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Exams"))
{
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Exam.TeacherId, new SelectList(Model.Teachers, "Id", "FullName"), "-- please select --", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Teacher" })
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Exam.TeacherId)
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your viewModel you can only send Exams , but in the query to fetch exams you must make a join to fetch for every exam the teacherID , teacherName , teacherSubname,
to Learn about that check this :
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67534732/entity-framework-join-two-tables-and-where-clause)
or this :
[here](https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-joining#:%7E:text=Entity%20Framework%20Core%20Joining&text=In%20SQL%2C%20a%20JOIN%20clause,using%20the%20Join()%20method.)

another thing , in your model ( classes ) definition , i think you have to add a relationship between Exam and Teacher , and between Teacher an People , if you do so it will be easier to fetch only the necessary data , and you will use only one property ( exams ) in your viewModel to send data to the view, to do so check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911844/model-relationships-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I made the following join in the Create action:
`var teachers = (from d in _context.Teachers
join p in _context.People
on d.PersonId equals p.Id
select new
{
    Id = t.Id,
    FullName = p.FirstName + " " + p.Surname,
}).ToList();

var viewModel = new ExamViewModel
{
    Teachers = teachers,
};`

Comment: But I can't pass the join to the view and I receive this error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int Id, string FullName>>' to 'App.Models.Teacher'`

Comment: Also I forgot to add the relationships when creating the question, thanks for pointing that out. I added the relationships to my initial question. But I don't understand what you mean in your second paragraph. I checked all the links but unfortunately I don't get it.